# router.setRouteLeaveHook seems not working with nested routes

Tags: react-router

router.setRouteLeaveHook seems not working with nested routes.

Lets say I have following router structure

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={DeliveriesPage} />
  <Route path="add/:trackingNr" component={AddDeliveryPage} />
  <Route path="add" component={AddDeliveryPage} />
  <Route path="delivery/:trackingNr" component={DeliveryPage}>
    <IndexRoute component={DeliveryDetail} />
    <Route path="live" component={LiveTracking} />
    <Route path="slots" component={Timeslots} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="addresses" component={AddressesPage} />
  <Route path="address/:id" component={EditAddress} />
  <Route path="address/:id/map" component={Map} />
  <Route path="settings" component={SettingsPage} />
  <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
</Route>
```

And want to set setRouteLeaveHook method in Timeslots component.

```
class Timeslots extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { route } = this.props;
    const { router } = this.context;
    router.setRouteLeaveHook(route, this.routerWillLeave);
  }

  routerWillLeave() {
    //do something on leave
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work for transition between sibling routes. EG:

- /delivery/:trackingNr/slots -> /delivery/:trackingNr/live (doesn't
  work)
- /delivery/:trackingNr/slots -> /delivery/:trackingNr (doesn't
  work)

It only seems to work for transitions their not siblings of a route that I'm transition from. EG:

- /delivery/:trackingNr/slots -> /address (works fine)

The reasons seems to be that route prop is always same for nested routes.

```
router.setRouteLeaveHook(route, this.routerWillLeave);
```

Has anybody solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what happened here is that the value of `this.props.route` there is not what you expect.

If you're using something like `React.cloneElement` from the parent route, you may be overriding the value of the `route` prop on `<Timeslots>`.

Double-check that `route` is actually what you expect it to be there. It's probably not.

Comment: Hi Taion. I was cloning element in my parent route/component and passing all it's props to children. Solution is apparently to pass only props that is needed by child components (as you suggested on discordapp chat). Thank you for  saving my day.